# css html ie7 (ul and li tags) menu problem

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-7, render

I m having trouble with some code and the ie7 browser, its a vertical CATEGORY menu made with the ul tag, and css properties. Works fine with safari, ie8, firefox 3.5 and 3.6 but with ie7 A BIG LEFT MARGIN IS BEING CREATED This is the code that is being generated by the server:

```
    <div id="menu">  
    <ul><li><a class="level1" href="catalog.html?category=21">PRODUCTOS</a></li>  
<li><a class="level1" href="catalog.html?category=21">Daniela Kosan</a></li>  
<li><a class="level2" href="catalog.html?category=21">Lo Nuevo</a></li>  
<li><a class="level2" href="catalog.html?category=22">Fragancias</a></li>  
<li><a class="level2" href="catalog.html?category=23">Rostro</a></li>  
<li><a class="level2" href="catalog.html?category=24">Accesorios</a></li></ul>
    </div>
```

and this is the css i'm using:

*{
    margin-top:0;
    padding:0;
}

```
#menu{
    background:#fff;
    width:205px;

    padding-left:9px;

}
    #menu ul{
        list-style:none;


    }
        #menu li{
            list-style:none;


        }
            #menu li a{
                list-style:none;
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                background:#F0CFD6;
                color:#944862;
                text-transform:none;
                font-size:14px;
                font-weight:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                display:block;


            }
                #menu li a:hover{
                    color:#fff;
                    text-decoration:none;
                }
            #menu li a.level1{
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-top:10px;
                width:205px;
                height:20px;
                color:#fff;
                background:#DA8298;


            }
                #menu li a:hover.level1{
                    color:#000;
                }
            #menu li a.level2{
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-top:12px;
                width:205px;
                height:20px;
                color:#8B5169;
                border-width:0 0px 0px 0px;
                background:#F0CFD6;
                border-bottom:1px dashed #CEABB2;

            }
                #menu li a:hover.level2{
                    color:#000;
                }
```

Here is the bad render, NOTE THE BIG LEFT MARGIN BESIDES THE CATEGORY MENU
[image]

This is how it renders on the other browsers... good! Thank you guys!
[image]

Comment: Why are you only resetting `margin-top`? Why not `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` ?

Comment: well i need a padding for left for the whole container so it matches the design. and i added the below answer to that tag and it worked, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the margin and padding on the `ul`. Different browser will automatically set it to different things. I suggest using a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in the future.

```
#menu ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    }
```

Try the above and let me know if it works. I don't have IE, so I can't test it. I'd test the margin and padding one at a time to see if only one of them is the culprit.

Comment: did work, however i got it working using adding the tags in the *{
 margin-top:0;
 padding:0;
 margin-left:0px;
}